# Why doesn't my fig tree produce fruit?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, figs

I have a fig tree but it hasn't had any fruits on it yet. I don't know which variety it is, I got it when it was only a few inches high. It's planted on a West facing wall of my bungalow,  but like I said has never had any fruit on it, not even any sign that they are going to form. I have seen plenty of other fig trees. It's over 7 feet tall and growing very healthy.

Comment: How old is it? It can take a fig tree a few years before it starts to develop fruit. What is your location? In cold climates they need protection in winter. Do you prune it? If so how/when? What other care, such as fertilizing, do you give it?

Answer (score 6):

Figs are pollinated by species specific wasps. Figs have an inconspicuous flower and if the wasps are not present you will not get fruit set.

- are there other figs in the neighbourhood that are flowering?
- figs require a spell of cool weather when their soil is kept drier. Does this happen where you live?
- also see this [excellent answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/509/what-is-the-proper-way-to-prune-a-fig-tree?rq=1) on pruning

Comment: That's true of some figs, but others are self pollinating or we wouldn't be able to grow figs where I'm at. You have to look at the type of fig plant and see if it requires a specific pollinator.

Answer (score 4):

By the way, not all figs require wasps for pollination.  In fact, most grown here in the US do not. Some varieties commonly grown without pollination include LSU Gold, Hollier, Sal's, Excell, Negronne, Brown Turkeys, Deanna, Hardy Chicago, Atreano, Paradiso, Black Spanish, Verte, Osborne Prolific, Conadria, and Lattarula.  If yours is one of these, or another type of "common" fig, then pollination is not your problem.

If you could give more information, then we might be able to help you narrow down the issue that's causing your fig to not produce fruit.