# Why did my fig tree stop making fruit?

Tags: fruit-trees, figs

Six years ago I planted a fig tree that was given to me.  I was told it was a "dwarf" fig but there has never been anything dwarf about it.  Within a couple of years of planting the tree it began producing very large (nearly the size of an egg) figs that were very juicy and the best tasting fig I've eaten.

Then three years ago we had a snow storm (rare here in Alabama) with single digit temperatures and the tree died back to the roots.  It has since grown back to its original size (probably 12' tall) but has never produced another fig.  We do not water or fertilize the tree and never have.  The tree I was given was started from a cutting and was not grafted.

[image: The fig tree in question]

Does anyone know why this tree has become sterile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my fig tree produce fruit?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/why-doesnt-my-fig-tree-produce-fruit)

Comment: @J.Chomel I think this differs. The question here is asking what happened causing the tree to stop producing fruit. The possible duplicate is asking about a tree that has never fruited. I'm voting to leave this open.

Comment: Also, the author of the other question hasn't been seen on the network since posting it, whereas the author here is available to answer questions and provide more information to the community.

Comment: If the tree was grafted, it's possible the snow storm killed the grafted part, leaving only the root that only has good vegetative properties. @Sue, I suggested the duplicate because it had answers and possibly one to this question.

Comment: @  J. Chomel, this tree was from a cutting that was rooted.  To everyone else...  It has sprouted a few figs!  I guess it just took some time to recover from the freeze.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your "dwarf fig" is not so dwarfed anymore is because it was reproduced via cutting.  The root stock that would have the cutting grafted to it is what determines the size of the mature shrub.

To answer your question though, I think it is probably still recovering from the stress of having to completely regrow.

Answer (score 2):

Plants are asexual if there was a time that it started getting less light or more light it can flip the plant into stay INTHE vegetative state.  Really there is nothing to do but wait and see if the summer months bring out the female in the plant and it will then if the lighting is good flower or produce fruit.